# Satellite dll:s from Nuget not working when compiling with .NET Native tool chain

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, nuget, .net-native, satellite-assembly

I have a Xamarin Forms PCL Project consuming a nuget package. The nuget package contains translated texts in satellite dll:s (xyz.resources.dll).

The translated texts shows up correctly in Android and iOS. They do also work for UWP when compiled with ".NET Native Tool Chain = false". However, if I DO check the ".NET Native Tool Chain" checkbox, the text is NOT translated. Only the resource from the "base-language" gets loaded.

I guess the .NET Native compilation somhow skips the satellite dll:s when trying to reduce the size of it's output.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried to generate the nuget package in release model ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved (even if it might be considered a bug).
I have two nuget packages and one xamarin forms solution.
Nuget pkg A = only Resources (translations)
Nuget pkg B = PCL:s and stuff

Nuget Pkg B refers Nuget Pkg A in order to use some texts.

My xamarin solution refers both Nuget pkg A and B. Since my UWP Project in the xamarin solution needs a referens to pkg B, it somehow gets confused by B:s Connection to A.

If, however, I break the Connection between nuget pkg A and B it all works fine. (I know, messy answer, but if someone has a similiar problem, let me know, and I'll try to explain it in a better way...)